# Huge file with 55000 rows * 1800 Columns - need to delete only specific column with a partial pattren

Tags: awk

I have a huge file (cancer Gene expression data- ~ 2 GBs .csv file) with 55000 rows and ~ 1800 Columns. so my table looks like this:

```
TCGA-4N-A93T-01A-11R-A37K-07, **TCGA-5M-AAT4-11A-11R-A41B-07**,     TCGA-5M-AATE-01A-11R-A41B-07,   TCGA-A6-2677-01B-02R-A277-07,   **TCGA-A6-2677-11A-01R-0821-07**
```

for example in Column `TCGA-5M-AAT4-11A-11R-A41B-07` at the fourth position I have `-11A`, Now my problem is I have to delete the entire columns which have `-11A` at 4th position (`xx-xx-xx-11A-xx-xx-xx`).This has to search all 1800 columns and keep only those columns which do not have `-11A` at a fourth position.

Can you please help me what command should i use to get the required data.
I am a biologist and have limited Experience in coding

EDITED:
I have a data file collected from 1800 Breast cancer patient, the table has got 55000 gene names as rows and 1800 samples as the columns. (55000 * 1800 matrix file)Few samples designed by our lab were faulty and we have to remove those from our analysis. Now, I have identified those samples and I wanted to remove them from my file1.csv. xx-xx-xx-11A-xx-xx-xx are the faulty samples, i need to identify only those samples and remove them from the file.csv. The samples which show 11A in the fourth place of the column name. I can do this in R but it takes too long for me to process. Thanks in advance, sorry for annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this is very broad. Likely lots of ways to modify a csv. Just note that you'll likely need to create a new csv with your specific data filtered out. A csv file is not really something set up for live updates (unlike, say, a database or a spreadsheet).

Comment: We don't need such a wide set of sample data to help you solve your problem. Also, it will be better if you add another "record" that should skipped from processing, and then include your required output from your 2 sample "records". (Has your data been correctly edited above, to have a separate line, or are those numbers just  your way of indicating a field?) If so, maybe `------1-------  -------------2--------------------` will be more helpful illustrating your problem. Good luck.

Comment: AND where are the commas? (`,`)? . If  it is really tab-separated data, (much better in my opinion), then convert tabs to `|` chars (at least in your sample data) so the fields are clearly visible. Good luck.

Comment: Oops Sorry for that Bad Post. I hope it dint offended you much.I will delete it.

Comment: Why on Earth people have an idea to *downvote* this?? People, ley me explain. This guy works on CANCER. His work is probably more beneficial to humanity than anything you will do ever in your life, to put it brutally. Additionally, he honestly admitted he has very limited experience. And there are oversmart guys downvoting him because he didn't meet their expectations. Jesus.

Comment: @WojciechKaczmarek - Why such a hostile outburst? Subject area doesn't matter here. Thousands of questions here could be for systems  just as important to humanity, without calling that out. There are specific site guidelines, types of questions that can be asked here, & what is considered off-topic. I cannot explain why people up- or downvote. It's part of the self-moderation of this site. Blasting the community with condescending remarks, how their work pales in comparison to the OP's, or that they voted, is uncalled for. Please see [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Subject area does matter. Always. Because it's life. It does not have less meaning just because you are smart enough to cite the rules.  Also, I can't see how the thing is offtopic. OP has given enough information for others to provide working code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#! /usr/local/bin/gawk -f
# blacklist_columns.awk
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578756

# i.e. TCGA-5M-AAT4-11A-11R-A41B-07
BEGIN{
    PATTERN="TCGA-..-....-11A-...-....-.."
}
$0 ~ ".*" PATTERN ".*"{ # matches rows with the pattern
    for(col=1;col<=NF; col++)
        # find column(s) in the row with the patten
        if($col ~ PATTERN){
            blacklist[col]++   # note which column
        }
}

END{ # output the list collected
    n = asorti(blacklist)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        bl=bl "," blacklist[i]
    print substr(bl, 2)
}

# Usage try ... :
#  BLACKLIST=blacklist_columns.awk table.tab
#
#  cut --complement -f $BLACKLIST table.tab > table_purged.tab
```

You can't do it in one pass so you might as well let an existing tool
do the second pass especially since you are more on the wet side.

The script should spit out a list of columns it thinks you should skip

you can feed that list as an argument to the program `cut` 
and get it to only keep the columns *not* mentioned.

Edit(orial):

Thank you for your sentiment Wojciech Kaczmarek I could not agree more.
There is also a flip side where some biologist discount "coders" which I find annoying. The paper being working on here may include some water cooler collaborator but fail to mention technical help on a show stopper (hey, they fixed it must not have been any big deal).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you really asking for, this script will delete row by row the fields which has the "11A" in the 4th position (based on `-` delim).

```
$ awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                              {split($i,a,"-");
                               if(a[4]=="11A") $i=""}}1' input > output
```

If you're asking to remove the entire column for all rows not just the found row, this is not it.  Also not tested but perhaps will give you ideas...

Comment: Beware of patterns in the field separator. Not all the world's a system with GNU awk.